# I cannot run button that implement onclick listener on another class

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Can somebody tell me how to work this?

Main Activity

```
MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
    MyListener listener = new MyListener();

    Button b = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

        b.setOnClickListener(new MyListener(MainActivity.this));
    }
}
```

My Listener Class

```
class MyListener implements View.OnClickListener{
    private Context context;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "You click me!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Also, if I implement Click listener here I am getting MainActivity needs to be declared abstract or Implement abstract method on OnClick

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener
```

Same error as above abstract/implement

```
public class ActivityMain extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    b.setOnClickListener(ActivityMain.this);

    @Override
    public void onClick (View view){
        Toast.makeText(ActivityMain.this, "You click me!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Hi Salman Tariq, I wanna show toast once the button is click that is on another class, but I'm having several problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to implement `View.OnClickListener`.

You can do like this.

```
class MyListener implements View.OnClickListener{

    private Context context;

    public MyListener(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "You Click Me!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Another click area.

```
new MyListener(MainActivity.this).onClick(view);
```

You can solve it.

Comment: Hi KeLiuyue, thank you for the answer. Pls. check above I cannot run toast MainActivity.this is not an enclosing class.

Comment: @JaysonJohn Hi,JaysonJohn,you can do it this way.

Comment: Hi KeLiuyue, it doesn't work well. The toast run once the project launch and not once I click the button.

Comment: @JaysonJohn  Hi,JaysonJohn,I modified you code. You can look at it.

Comment: @JaysonJohn  I'm glad to help you.

Comment: Hi KeLiuyue, I have a final question> 

Why I can't implement my View.OnClickListener on my Main Activity it returns with an error that needs to be abstract??

Comment: If you implement  ` View.OnClickListener`,You must implement  `onClick(View view)` method.Otherwise,you must set MainActivity to abstract.

Comment: Pls. check above code. I am still getting the same error

Comment: @JaysonJohn you can have a look.